# How to add diffrent prefix to file names in a folder using Windows command line (reading prefix names from textfile)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-processing

I got a huge list of images in a folder (3000 images). Now I want to add a prefix to all these image names. The prefix for each image is different and the prefix is obtained from a text file.

My text file looks like this

```
mango,A.jpg
apple,B.jpg
orange,c.jpg
```

and i want to change image names fromA.jpg,B.jpg,C.jpg to:

```
mango_A.jpg
apple_B.jpg
orange_C.jpg
```

Could any one tell me how this can be done using a windows batch file?

Comment: Look at [FOR /F](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18177593/463115) and [arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10196352/463115)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, try this:

```
pushd C:\..[Folder Path]
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (list.txt) do (
ren "%%~b" "%%~a_%%~b"
)
```

And you're done!

Comment: Thanks for replies. Monacraft can you tell me how run the above ? furthermore do i need to change this part :ren "%%~b" "%%~a_%%~b" ? or only the texfile name ? can this method work for like 2000 image files without freezing or crushing ?

Comment: look at my edit, and rename the text file list.txt. Also, copy and paste this into a batch file by: opening notepad, pasting this into it, saving as * all file types * and replacing .txt with .bat.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Mona's suggestion but is a little more robust, even if you have finished the task.

The prefix should not contain a comma, else the first comma will be where the prefix is taken up to.

Place `this batch file` and `list.txt` in the folder with your files and launch the batch file.

As it stands it will `echo` each rename command and `pause` for a keypress, for you to verify that it is doing what you need to do.

Remove the `echo` and `pause` to make it functional.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=," %%a in (list.txt) do (
   if exist "%%b" echo ren "%%b" "%%a_%%b"
   pause
)
```